# Bash for loop - change variable name

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have a for loop that takes a CIDR that contains an illegal character for file names ("/").

part of the command is to save the output with the name of the CIDR.

```
for i in $(more subnets.lst);do shodan download $i-shodan net:$i;done
```

the download argument is followed by the result of the more command, which are the CIDR (192.168.21.0/24).

is there a way in bash to rename a variable while the loop is running ? 
I remember doing this years back in batch files by subtracting from the str length, but that won't help me as I just need to replace the "/" with a "-"(or any other compliant char.

Comment: Note that you can provide multiple subnets to the "net" filter in Shodan by separating them with a comma. For example, you can do:

net:192.168.21.0/24,172.20.0.0/16,8.8.8.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with using `bash` Parameter Expansion:

```
$ echo $var
192.168.21.0/24

$ echo "${var//\//-}"
192.168.21.0-24
```

So in your command, just use `"${i//\//-}"` whenever needed without changing the original value of `$i`. If you want to set variable `i` to the new value:

```
i="${i//\//-}"
```

---

On a side note, use `while` loop to read lines from a file, not `cat`, `more` or brothers, like:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do ....; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out for myself:

```
for i in $(more subnets-test);do shodan download $(echo $i | tr "/" "-") net:$i;done
```